# django two templates inside eachother Could not parse the remainder

Tags: django, django-templates

I've got the error `Could not parse the remainder: '"' from '"'` in this part of my code:

```
{% include 'test.html' with pic_url="{% static 'picture.jpg' %}" %}
```

Is it possible to write something like this in Django templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot combine template tags like this.

What you can do instead is to assign result of one template tag to variable. It is not possible with all template tags, but it is possible with `static` tag:

```
{% static 'blog-single.html' as some_variable %}
{% include 'test.html' with post_url=some_variable %}
```